# How to know if the scrollbar is dragged using jquery

Tags: jquery, position, scrollbar, drag

How to know if the scrollbar is dragged? or change position? using jquery.
I will place it here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

so It will trigger when the user scrolls to bottom.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "scroll" event.

```
$("someElement").on( "scroll", handler );
```

Or the shorthand [`scroll`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) method

```
$("someElement").scroll(handler);
```

Here is a quick fiddle to show how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/3SLzW/